# Unmarsheller.unmarshal(Source) api not available with JDK1.7

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I'm not able to compile the below JAXB Unmarshalling code using JDK1.7.

```
    private Foo retrieveUnmarshalData(Source source) {  
    try {  
     JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);  
     Unmarsheller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarsheller();  
     JAXBElement<Foo> jaxbElement = (JAXBElement<Foo>)unmarshaller.unmarshal(source);  
     Foo foo = jaxbElement.getValue();
     return foo;    
    }  
    catch(JAXBException exception){
      // catch exception
    }
```

When I try to compile the above code  **unmarshaller.unmarshal(source)**  API is not available with JDK1.7.

I have visited many forums but no luck. If anyone faced this issue earlier kindly let me know that changing the unmarshalling logic is the only option or any other API's will solve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure? It appears to be in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshal(javax.xml.transform.Source)). Could you please post a SSCCE in order to make it clearer what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

The unmarshal from `Source` method is definitely still present in the JAXB 2.2 APIs that are included in Java SE 7 (JDK 1.7).

- [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshal(javax.xml.transform.Source)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshal%28javax.xml.transform.Source%29)

Since Java SE 7 contains the `javax.xml.transform` APIs you will need to be sure you are not bundling them into your app or adding another version into the class path that conflicts.  Also if you are using an OSGi environment make sure you import the `javax.xml.transform` package in your manifest.

Comment: Thanks all for your valuable suggestions. javax jar is taking precedence and showing me only 2 api's. When I remove javax.jar from my lib, I'm not getting any compilation errors. Issue resolved.